# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly office. perhaps doesn't exist in the Mono for Android Profile?

Tags: c#, excel, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on creating excel file on mobile devices. I am trying to use **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll** for this. but after adding the reference, the build fails with below error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'office,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'office.dll'    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() App1

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can find good info in [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102998/mono-for-android-reading-and-writing-to-xlsx) and it might lead you to [open-xml-sdk-xamarin](https://github.com/wotzisname/open-xml-sdk-xamarin)

Comment: @BassemAkl, possible to provide example/guide which me in its usage?

Answer (score 1):

The CIL-based Assembly that you are trying to add to your project contains references to native Windows-based dlls that will not run under Xamarin.Android (or Xamarin.iOS).

There are several options for working with `.xlsx` files within Xamarin ranging from commercial to open source projects.

#### Examples:

> TMS Flexcel Studio for .NET
>
> 100% managed code Excel file manipulation engine & Excel & PDF report generation for .NET, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Mac

https://blog.xamarin.com/generate-excel-spreadsheets-in-native-mobile-apps/
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp
https://components.xamarin.com/view/FlexCel/

> Open-XML-SDK-Xamarin

https://github.com/wotzisname/open-xml-sdk-xamarin

Comment: Can you please provide me an example or modify your answer to include one? I am not able to get the entry point.

Comment: From where to begin? I tried to search for Spreadsheet or DocumentType.Workbook. But I didn't find anything. Can you please provide an example?